# combining legend and paste command in base R plot

Tags: r, legend, paste

I want to `paste()` some text into the legend in my plot, but I cannot get R to correctly read the `c()` and `paste()` commands.

```
plot(1:10,1:10,type="n")

a <- 23
b <- 32

legend("topleft",inset=0.05,
       legend=c("1-15: n=[23]\nEstimated","15+: n=[32]\nAveraged"),
       lty=c(1,1),col=c("black","red"),bty="n",cex=1.5)

legend("topright",inset=0.05,
       legend=c(paste("1-15: n=[",a,"]\nEstimated","15+: n=[32]\nAveraged")),
       lty=c(1,1),col=c("black","red"),bty="n",cex=1.5)
```

so the legend on the left is manually created, my desired output is to create the same on the right hand side.

Answer (score 1):

You were close. I believe this is what you want:

```
plot(1:10, 1:10, type="n")
a <- 23
b <- 32

legend("topright", inset = 0.05,
       legend = c(paste("1-15: n=[", a, "]\nEstimated"),
                  paste(" 15+: n=[", b, "]\nAveraged")),
       lty = c(1,1),
       col = c("black","red"), bty = "n", cex = 1.5)
```

Comment: To avoid something like this `[ 32 ]` you would probably use `paste0`

Comment: sprintf might look nice here